# Cypress - test stops after navigating to another domain

Tags: authentication, cypress, cross-domain

Our team have been using Cypress as part as our E2E UI tests, however, we are running into some roadblocks where we can't write tests to cover some scenarios because the flow goes through a third party site.

We have several examples of this throughout our application:

- Our signup flow actually goes through a slightly different domain (it's still our app, just a slightly different domain), but because Cypress doesn't allow us to navigate to third party sites, the tests stops
- We have several integrations that requires the user to login through the third party site, and on success, they will be redirected back into our application. (We can do this through oauth... and as suggested by Cypress that would be the recommended way, but I feel that in doing so, it wouldn't exactly cover what we want to test, as we want to go through the steps of clicking the activate button, logging in, and being redirected back)

I was wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue and have found a solution or perhaps another alternative? While I agree that we should not be testing third party sites, what would be the option for our scenario?

We have tried setting `chromeWebSecurity: false`, however I believe this only works for Chrome...?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is required to cross the two domains, for example a token can be saved.

The trick would be to visit different domains in different tests. In the oauth example, test1 clicks the button and you confirm the navigation to the 3rd party site.

Test2 then retrieves the token and proceeds to test the local app as if it had been redirected from oauth.

I'm pretty sure it's covered in a Cypress recipe somewhere, will try to find it.